# Traverse a tree with an arbitrary number of branches

Tags: haskell

I want to calculate the maximum degree in a `Tree` which has an arbitrary number of branches.

```
data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]
  deriving (Eq, Show)

{-

       2
    /  |  \
   7   3   1
       |  / \
       0 3   2
 For this case: Answer will be 3. 
-}
tree1 :: Tree Int
tree1 = Node 2 [Node 7 [], Node 3 [Node 0 []], Node 1 [Node 3 [], Node 2 []]]

--I am doing something like this:

maxBranching :: Tree Int -> Int
maxBranching Node n [] = 1
maxBranching Node n xs = max (length xs) maxBranching xs
```

Now, I am getting an error. How can I write the correct pattern to solve this problem?

Comment: What error are you getting? I suppose you simply need to put brackets around `Node n *`, ie `(Node n [])` and `(Node n xs)`

Comment: • The constructor ‘Node’ should have 2 arguments, but has been given none
    • In the pattern: Node
      In an equation for ‘maxBranching’: maxBranching Node n [] = 1
      The equation(s) for ‘maxBranching’ have three arguments,
      but its type ‘Tree Int -> Int’ has only one
   |
22 | maxBranching Node n [] = 1

Comment: Sounds like my suggestion would fix that. Without parentheses around `Node n xs`, it thinks `n` and `xs` are second and third arguments to `maxBranching` instead of `Node`

Comment: Sounds like a job for Foldable?

Comment: @AnthonyRaimondo, `Foldable` isn't actually powerful enough for this job. `Foldable` effectively flattens out the very tree structure that needs to be examined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the type of parameter of `maxBranching` is `Tree Int` and not `[Tree Int]` and you want to map all Children Nodes to its maximum degrees, so it should be:

```
map maxBranching xs
```

Not

```
maxBranching xs
```

Secondly, parameter need in parentheses, otherwise, the function `maxBranching` become accept 3 parameters.

put them all as:

```
maxBranching :: Tree Int -> Int
maxBranching (Node _ []) = 1
maxBranching (Node _ xs) =  maximum $ (length xs) : (map maxBranching xs)
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to traverse a tree generating a sort of "summary value". This is a classic example of a *catamorphism* or *fold*. The general fold for trees looks like this:

```
foldTree :: (a -> [b] -> b) -> Tree a -> b
foldTree f (Node a bs) = f a (map (foldTree f) bs)
```

The idea here is that at each tree node,

```
Node r [t1,t2,t3]
```

we first reduce each child recursively to a summary value, then apply the given function and the root value and the summaries of the children to produce a summary for the tree.

Now

```
maxBranching :: Tree a -> Int
maxBranching = foldTree $
  \_ bs -> maximum (length bs : bs)
```

That is, at each node, we take the maximum of the number of branches of that node and each of its children.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to put parentheses around your argument, like this:

```
maxBranching (Node n xs) = ...
```

If you don't put parentheses around your arguments, the compiler can't know if `n` and `xs`/`[]` belongs to `Node` or `maxBranching`.

Next issue you have is that your recursive call is done on a list of `Tree Int` instead of just a `Tree Int`. What you need to do is to get the maxBranching of each subtree and then compare the result to each other. So a first, naive approach, would be the following:

```
maxBranching (Node n xs) = max (length xs) (maximum (map maxBranching xs))
```

`map` will run `maxBranching` on every element of the list `xs`, returning an array of `Int`. `maximum` will then take the max in the list. The difference between `max` and `maximum` is that `max` only takes two arguments and compare them, while `maximum` takes a list which is arbitrarily long.

We could get rid of `max`by adding `length xs` into the list we created, and running `maximum` on everything, like this:

```
maxBranching (Node n xs) = maximum $ (length xs):(map maxBranching xs)
```

And if you don't know, `$` is equvivalent with putting parantheses around the rest of the line (more or less).

You could also use smart methods as folding and the like, but I just wanted you to understand the errors you did and how to fix them without changing the core idea of your solution.

Comment: I tried your solution, but still I am getting error.

Comment: `xs` is of type `[Tree Int]` not a `Tree Int`